# prevent pytest from cleaning up?

Tags: pytest, django-testing

sometimes when I'm working on my tests, it would be realy helpful to be able to look at the state of the database in mid-test (or post-test).  for example:

```
def test_login(self):
    user = UserFactory.create(username="test_user", password="foobar")

    # there's typo in my username here
    response = self.client.post("/login", 
                                data={"username" : "testuser",
                                      "password" : "foobar"})

     # assert that we have logged in
```

So what I'd like is one of two options:

1) A command flag that says "run my test, but DON'T clean up the database when you're done."

B) A command flag that says, "run my test, but DON'T wrap everything in a database transaction -- I want to be able to set a breakpoint and then use my database tools to examine the database mid-test."

Is there anything like this?  I can't find it...

Comment: How you are performing clean up? By tear down method?

Comment: there's no explicit cleanup in my code.  I guess it could be Django's TestCase method that's doing it...